# Want to do custom coding on product descrption page(Magento)

Tags: magento

I am looking for a functionality some thing like as that of the following link:

http://www.steveandco.com/it/v/1988/Bretelle/Bretelle-stretta-Oro.html

Here when we click on the box meant for color selection the image and the associated information like unique  number , product name , color name changes.

Please guide me how I can achieve this on my magento installation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This commercial extension might do it. I think you have to use 'Configurable' products for it to work.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/temgra/extension/893/color-swatches